# Soundcard gets turned off after inactivity

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

For a couple of years I have a ASUS Sonar Essence STX internal sound card, running now on Xubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine, except that I noticed that if I stop using the computer for a few minutes, the sound is off when I come back to it.

The "manual" way to fix is to just open pavucontrol (on `Sound Settings...` on the panel bar), and by just switching the Port on the `Output Devices` - e.g, selecting `Headphones 2` and then going back to `Headphones 1` or `Speakers`.

The weird thing is that this is now more frequent. It used to happen after waking from resume, now it is happening just after a few minutes and even without going into screensaver. So now it is enough of a bother for me to try to find a solution for the issue.

I noticed that when I lose sound, this is what I get by running `pactl list sinks`

```
Sink #7
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_01.0.analog-stereo
    Description: CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] (Virtuoso 100 (Xonar ST)) Analog Stereo
(...)
```

After switching the port source thing, it becomes:

```
Sink #7
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_05_01.0.analog-stereo
    Description: CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio] (Virtuoso 100 (Xonar ST)) Analog Stereo
 (...)
```

Omitted parts are mostly similar.

The question is, is there any command that I can run to keep the device from being suspended? Should I look somewhere in Alsa? Is this something new from power settings? I could understand when it was happening after resuming, but now I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: ALSA does not suspend devices by its own. This is probably done by PulseAudio. (See the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Bluetooth_headset_replay_problems).)